# How integrate PTC with jenkins?

Tags: plugins, jenkins-plugins, integration

Can any one tell me what we should fill at host name section while we integrating PTC with jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Now i got the answer of my question:

For integrate PTC with jenkins we need to follow some steps those are mentioned in below link :
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PTC+Integrity+Plugin

and in Host Name: We need to give ip address of our server or host pc address which is for PTC.
Thanks.